# Excel - recursive calculated formula for all rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Im sure this question has been solved but I am new to excel and could not seem to find the answer from my research.
I would like to apply a simple calculation to each row then on the next row get a value from previous row to be applied for the same calculation.

> ```
>      +---------------+------------------+-----------------++-----------------+
>      |       A       |          B       |        C        |        D         |
>      +----------------------------------------------------+------------------+
>     1|               |                  |                 |   =SUM(B1:C1)    |
>      +----------------------------------------------------+------------------+
>     2|               |         =D1      |                 |   =SUM(B2:C2)    |
>      +---------------+------------------+-----------------+------------------+
>     3|               |         =D2      |                 |   =SUM(B3:C3)    |
>      +---------------+------------------+-----------------+------------------+
> ```

From this example, I would like to recursively apply this formula down columns B and D.

Any help will be appreciated,  thank you.

Comment: What's the issue here? It looks like dragging down these formulae will have the desired effect.

Comment: Just click the lower right corner of the cell then drag down to copy the formulae. It will automatically update the cells.

Comment: oh wow,  i had no idea this was a function, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use google sheets for my spreadsheets, but to my knowledge, it's roughly similar in major aspects. If you click on one of the cells with the formula, a small black box should appear in the bottom right corner of it, click it and drag it down and it should copy the formula, taking into account the change of row. I use this all the time to calculate win ratios for teams in leagues. Hope this helps!